# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App Starts and immediately terminates in Debugger

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 application that was just upgraded from Windows Phone 8. When the emulator starts and the app fires up, it immediately crashes to the app list. It doesn't get caught in the debugger at all. Just crashes hard.

The Windows Phone 8 version works fine and I've made sure that the splashscreen.png file is part of the project and is set as content as I've seen elsewhere but I'm at a loss as to what would cause this.

Anyone know what's going on? There's nothing in any logs I can find so I can't provide any further information to assist. Sorry!

Comment: There can be some method in your app's main page constructor or in App.xaml file which have been changed in wp8.1. Try to find out those methods. This could help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created a blank Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app and made sure that everything was identical when it came to main page constructor etc. and couldn't find anything. Putting a break point on the public App function doesn't get hit either.

Answer (score 2):

Found the Answer: When Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 updated the project, it for some reason cleared the "Startup Object" for the application which caused it to never hit any code which was why this was happening.

Setting this again to the only option fixed the problem. Of course this should compile-time fail with an error but it doesn't, so if you get this issue that's likely why.